# IE7 and IE8 do not honour default span behaviour

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to implement a pagination control on the following page:
http://equiniti.hireserve-projects.com/vacancies.html

As you can see when viewed in a decent browser such as Firefox, the pagination controls will appear nicely inline as shown below:

[image: Pagination]

However, when viewed in IE7 and IE8, the pagination controls appear as follows:
[image: Pagination IE]

By default, these elements should all appear inline so I do not understand why they are overlapping in this way. The following CSS is applied to these elements:

```
.paginationControls a{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    color: #424242;
}

.paginationControls a:hover,
span.arrowNext:hover,
span.arrowPrev:hover,
.paginationControls a.jp-current
{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #E41800;
}

span.arrowNext,
span.arrowPrev{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
}
```

The following is the structure of my HTML:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="arrowPrev">« Previous</span>
    <span class="paginationControls"></span>
    <span class="arrowNext">Next »</span>
</div>
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening when spans should appear inline by default? I've tried the usual trick of ensuring that the parent element isn't floated but this doesn't make any difference in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is in native IE7 and IE8 on a virtual machine.

Comment: IE7 and IE8 do not honor web standards full stop. :)

Comment: I wouldn't call Firefox a 'decent browser' anymore. Firefox is the new IE

Comment: No my ears are burning :(

Comment: @3rror404 What?! [citation needed] :)

Comment: Can you set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem? It's hard to figure out what's going on without seeing some HTML and the rest of your CSS too.

Comment: @error404 Yeah that's a bit of an odd comment there. Bit unjustified really. Never had any problems with Firefox when it comes to implementing web standards.

Comment: Cannot setup a fiddle as JS fiddle is unsupported in IE8 and IE7 so there would be no point.

Comment: @jezzipin FF is so buggy these days and I've found the need to use hacks on numerous occasions recently. Never used to happen. And that's not due to my sloppy code before you say it :)

Comment: If you have to result to hacks then most of the time you aren't handling things correctly.

Comment: @error404 Ha! If anything I've had completely the opposite experience, with variants on the Webkit/Blink theme causing me problems. I guess we must be doing very different things.

Comment: Don't get me wrong; webkit isn't perfect either.

Comment: @3rror404 Firefox is king. I have to hack other browsers to make them work as firefox does... correctly! Do you have any specific failures of firefox? http://ie7.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to test IE8 but please try applying:

```
.pagination span{
    display:inline-block
}
```

As I recall span tags do not render as block level elements by default.
You should also specify a min-height and min-width to force a block.

Alternatively use a div instead of a span tag.

Comment: For IE7, you'll need `display: inline; zoom: 1;`  to achieve the same effect (either in a separate selector or using something like the star hack).